# Settings a Displayfield value a second time tooks quite to long

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Can anyone tell me way the second time I am setting the value of a displayfield it took ExtJS arround ~300ms per field to set the value? I already tried to use `setRawValue()` instead of `setValue()` but it is all the same. A simple profiling shows that the time is consumed by the following lines:

```
me.inputEl.dom.innerHTML = me.getDisplayValue();
me.updateLayout();
```

**Edit:**
*A further Prifiling shows that `me.updateLayout();` took all the time.*

Any Idea how I can speed this up? I tested it with ExtJS 4.1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve performance by using [`Ext.suspendLayouts()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-suspendLayouts) before you start setting the fields. Once you've set all your fields, use [`Ext.resumeLayouts(true)`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-resumeLayouts)

Comment: From ~300ms per field to ~500ms for all fields (~30 fields)